# Ways to control time interval between animation with c++ qt

Tags: c++, qt, animation, delay, qtimer

In an assignment, we are supposed to use c++ and qt to display a series of color changes to a button, with each color lasting a variable amount of time depending on certain inputs. The professor suggested using QTimer singleshot to accomplish this, which calls a certain slot after a certain amount of time.

I attempted to do so by looping through the animation list and creating a series of singleshots, incrementing the wait each time by the length of the color change. However, the actual length of time the animation last varies quite a bit from the time specified.

My suspicion is that the loop that creates the singleshots and the nature of threads firing off messes up the singleshot timers. Is there a way to do the animations with reliable timing without diving into the multi-threaded mess?

If there isn't, how would I go about doing it in a multi-threaded way without having to completely restructure my code around the threads? Thanks!

Comment: Unless the threads are required by other parts of the assignment, I don't see a need for them. Create a singleshot timer. When that elapses change the color of the button, and then create another singleshot timer. Repeat.

Answer (score 0):

> However, the actual length of time the animation last varies quite a bit from the time specified.

Without seeing your code, I assume you've setup an array of times and your expectation of when they will fire is wrong, because it's an accumulation of the times, rather than the time itself. This would occur if you're calling the next time from inside the slot connected to timeout.

Here's an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate:

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{    
public:
    MyClass();

    void Start()
    {
        UpdateButton(0);
    }

    void UpdateButton(int delayIdx);

    void TimedOut(int delay)
    {
        qDebug("Timed Out %d", delay);
    }

private:
    QList<int> m_delayList;
};

MyClass::MyClass()
    : QObject(NULL)
{
    m_delayList.push_back(3000); // 3 seconds
    m_delayList.push_back(3000); 
    m_delayList.push_back(5000);
}

void MyClass::UpdateButton(int delayIdx)
{
    if(delayIdx == m_delayList.count())
        return;

    QTimer* pTimer = new QTimer(this);
    pTimer->setSingleShot(true);

    int delay = m_delayList[delayIdx++];
    connect(pTimer, &QTimer::timeout, [=](){

        TimedOut(delay);
        UpdateButton(delayIdx); // use of recursion
        pTimer->deleteLater();

    });
    pTimer->start(delay);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);  
    MyClass cls;
    cls.Start();            
    return a.exec();
}
```

So, in this example, the class has a list of delays. It may appear that the first two will fire at the same time (after 3000ms), but when we run, the first will fire after 3 seconds, the 2nd after 6 and the 3rd after 11 seconds because each consecutive timer is setup after the previous one has fired.